# How to lock one Response after hitting submit button in making Quiz App

Tags: java, android, xml

I am making a Quiz app where I have created 2 buttons ,one for submit and other to move to next Question

I Want to code it in such a way that if I hit Submit button the response gets recorded and doesn't change after it:

My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.vidit.project3.question1">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/q1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/rg">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/correct"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a3" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/a4"
        android:id="@+id/last" />



</RadioGroup>


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rg"
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:text="SUBMIT"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:onClick="submit1"
    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="NEXT"
    android:onClick="toQuestion2"/>


</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.example.vidit.project3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class question1 extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);
}

public void submit1(View v)
{


    RadioButton rb= (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.correct);
    if(rb.isChecked())
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Whopiee!       Correct Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Arghh! Incorrect Answer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

}

public void toQuestion2(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,question2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}





}
```

Comment: "*the response gets recorded and doesn't change after it*"...the solution depends on how and when you'd utilize this response...please elaborate.

Comment: have you tried using shared preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will disable all the radio buttons. Is that what you want?

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++)     
 {   
    radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);   
 }
```

Comment: Its Showing cannot resolve radioGroup in symbol and is highlighted in  red

Comment: @ViditShah get a reference to the radiogroup by doing findViewbyId

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this  by storing the response of answer in Map and need to be check in the map if the Question exists , then disable the options otherwise open the options.

```
Map<Question,Response> quizResponse = new HashMap();
```

Now add your all questions one by one in this Map and check

```
if(quizResponse.contains(question))
{ radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false); // Disable the button

}
else
{
// show the question
quizResponse.put(question, response); // this response can be blank and update once you got user response

}
```